# ACF, Categories and Featured Image for a custom post / relationship on WP REST API

Tags: php, wordpress, graphql, gatsby, wordpress-rest-api

I'm building a Gatsby site that sources from a WP back end with GraphQL. I'm having issues preparing my data to send over through the API.

I have a custom post called case studies. These case studies have categories, a featured image and several ACF fields that I need to be able to access through REST. I've created a custom REST API endpoint for my case studies as such:

```
/************************************************
 * Case Study REST API Endpoint
 * *************************************************/ 
function caseStudyEndpoint( $request_data ) {

  // setup query argument
  $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'case-study',
      'posts_per_page' => -1
  );

  // get posts
  $posts = get_posts($args);

  // add custom field data to posts array 
  foreach ($posts as $key => $post) {
          $posts[$key]->acf = get_fields($post->ID);
          $posts[$key]->link = get_permalink($post->ID);
          $posts[$key]->image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post->ID);
          $posts[$key]->categories = wp_get_post_categories($post->ID);
  }
  return $posts;
}

// register the endpoint;
add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'case_study_endpoint/v2', '/case-studies/', array(
      'methods' => 'GET',
      'callback' => 'caseStudyEndpoint',
      )
  );
});
```

Through this endpoint I can easily access all the fields, including featured image, ACF and categories.

In addition, I have an ACF block called Related Case Studies, which has a number of relationship fields that link to case studies. From that block, I can also retrieve the ACF for the related case study, as well as the categories, image and such. I'm able to accomplish this thanks to this recursive snippet.

```
/**
* ACF, Image and Category Data in Post Object Response
*/

$types = ['post', 'page', 'case-study'];

foreach ( $types as $type ) {
    add_filter( 'acf/rest_api/'.$type.'/get_fields', function( $data, $response ) use ( $types ) {

        if ( $response instanceof WP_REST_Response ) {
            $data = $response->get_data();
        }

        array_walk_recursive( $data, 'deepIncludeFields', $types );

        return $data;

    }
    , 10, 3 );
}

function deepIncludeFields( &$item, $key, $postTypes ) {
    if ( isset( $item->post_type ) && in_array( $item->post_type, $postTypes ) ) {
        $item->acf = get_fields( $item->ID );
        $item->image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($item->ID);
        $item->categories = wp_get_post_categories($item->ID, array( 'fields' => 'names' ));
    }
}
```

So I am covered in being able to retrieve all my data for a case study by accessing the Case Study endpoint and I'm also able to retrieve all the data recursively from a relationship field while using my regular WordpressPage endpoint.

However, within the case studies themselves I am also hoping to have the Related Case Studies block, and to be able to access the data for other case studies recursively from there as well. But this isn't working.

This is the data that I can access for the Related Case Study block within my WordpressPage query from GraphQL:

[image]

As you can see, ACF, image and categories are there.

But when I try to access that same block from within the Case Study, using my allWordpressCaseStudyEndpointCaseStudies query, I am not seeing the same results.

[image]

Neither ACF, image or categories are popping up in there.

I know I'm very close, and the solution might be to use a different WP filter for my recursive ACF function, or something. Basically the ACF Recursion is missing within the Case Study Custom post endpoint.

I'm using ACF to REST API on Wordpress.

Hopefully this all makes sense. Let me know if you have any feedback.

Comment: Do you know about `wp-graphql`? As far as I can understand that your rest API is sending the right response but your graphql is not. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SharifMohammadEunus do know about wp-graphql. But it's unclear what the level of effort would be to restucture the site not to use the REST API and use the WPGRAPHQL API instead. I figured there would be something that could be done on the WP REST side to fix this issue before changing a bunch of stuff.